# KnockoutJS Maths

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I'm new to knockout and still getting my head around it and I'm wondering how I go about doing simple mathematics (addition and multiplication) using two KO variables.

At the minute I have:

```
self.popInc1 = ko.observable('0.3');
self.popIncrease = ko.computed(function () {
    return self.popInc1() + " x " +  self.population();
});
```

Which is great as it returns and prints out: "**0.3 x 54,556,239**"

However I'd like to multiply the two variables together. I have tried the following to no success.

```
self.popInc1 = ko.observable('0.3');
self.popIncrease = ko.computed(function () {
    return Math.floor(self.popInc1() * self.population());
});
```

At the minute 0.3 is static, but will eventually be dynamic from a text input.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/barryman9000/UNaUk/2/

```
<div data-bind="text: popIncrease"></div>
<input type="text" data-bind="value: userInput,  valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" />


var ViewModel = function(){
    var _self = this;
    _self.userInput = ko.observable(0.3);
    _self.population = ko.observable(54556239);

    _self.popIncrease = ko.computed(function () {
        return Math.floor(_self.userInput() * _self.population());
    });
};
```

**UPDATE**
I see you resolved the issue but thought I'd include this other fiddle. You can just supply a zero in your `_self.population()` observable when it's initialized, then in whatever function you're using to get that value from the array, you can update the observable and your calculation should work fine
http://jsfiddle.net/barryman9000/UNaUk/3/

```
_self.population = ko.observable(0);
```

Comment: That works if I define population as a fixed value, however it's dynamic and predefined from earlier on in the app. The figure is pulled from an array and the number used depends on another option. So to reiterate, if I put self.population = ko.observable(123), it works, if I remove 123, I get NaN

Comment: self.population must be right because it prints out the correct value(s) in the view

Comment: The NaN value is because _self.userInput and _self.population was uninitialized. You could do a simple check if the values are undefined, then return 0, else do the computation.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it, my original value that's pulled from the array was a string rather than a number. facepalm.